# golang type conversion in unmarshaljson

Tags: go

Could someone help me please what's going wrong here? For some reason the output are not the same and I don't get why.

```
type rTime time.Time

func (rt *rTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", s)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Println(t)

    *rt = rTime(t)

    log.Println(*rt)
    return nil
}
```

Log looks like this:

```
2014/09/18 04:31:35 1999-10-15 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2014/09/18 04:31:35 {63075542400 0 0x933ea0}
```

Why's the conversion not working? The input string is `1995-10-15` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion is working, but `fmt.Println()` looks for a `String()` method, and that exists on `time.Time` but not on your type. You should need nothing more than `func (rt rTime) String() string { return time.Time(rt).String() }` to direct `String()` calls back to `time.Time`'s implementation.

[Here's an example](http://play.golang.org/p/XHwIfen-aH):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type rTime time.Time

func (rt rTime) String() string { return time.Time(rt).String() }

func main() {
    s := "1999-10-15"
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(t)

    rt := rTime(t)

    log.Println(rt)
}
```

Note that I treated both time types as values because [the standard library does](http://golang.org/pkg/time/), per [the canonical advice to avoid pointers for tiny structs with value semantics](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Pass_Values).

Maybe more interesting, you can use [type embedding](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) to automagically pick up all of the methods of `time.Time` except any you override. The syntax changes slightly ([see on Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HR9SR6t_NS)):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type rTime struct { time.Time }

func main() {
    s := "1999-10-15"
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(t)

    rt := rTime{t}

    log.Println(rt)
}
```

If you've used embedding and want to write your own *custom* methods that "proxy through" to the embedded type's, you use a syntax like obj.EmbeddedTypeName.Method, which could be like, for instance, `rt.Time.String()`:

```
// a custom String method that adds smiley faces
func (rt rTime) String() string { return " " + rt.Time.String() + " "  }
```

obj.EmbeddedTypeName is also how you (for example) access operators on non-`struct` types that you've embedded.

Comment: Oh, nice, thanks for the explanation! Problem is though, I want to insert this data into MongoDB, but it's just empty there. I'm getting JSON data from a url then I unmarshal it and keep the data I need then insert into Mongo. is there a way to handle rTime as time.Time so `mgo` will recognise it?

Comment: I'm not sure if, where, or how `mgo` special-cases `time.Time` so I can't help you there. You could post a separate question with a complete code sample and maybe somebody more knowledgeable about `mgo` might be able to help.

Comment: Actually, now I do know: it special cases it [in its bson encoder](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2/bson/encode.go#L401). It needs a real `time.Time`, not something satisfying some interface, so you need to make sure it actually gets that; how best to do that in your app I don't know.

Comment: Ah! I think you can just implement `GetBSON()` on `rTime`; have that return the `time.Time`:  http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Getter

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you figure out how to convert it back to time.Time for the db insert? I'm running into the same issue where I'm able to get the conversion via the unmarshaljson as you are, but cannot then get the custom time.Time to insert into the db (in this case google datastore)